# time reversal symmetry is broken by magnetic field

Tags: time-reversal-symmetry

In literature, the saying "the time reversal symmetry is broken by the external magnetic field" appears very often. How to understand this statement?

Comment: A magnetic field is often generated by a current. After time reversal the current is going in the opposite direction and the field changes sign.

Comment: Or, consider a proton traveling through a magnetic field. The path will be curved. Now 'reverse time', that is, flip the velocity vector. Will the proton retrace its path through the magnetic field?

Comment: @JonCuster Is this happening because the magnetic field is not reversed simultaneously with the reversal of velocity?